# Eviction Event Listeners for Caffeine or any JVM Cache API?

Tags: java, caching, hazelcast, caffeine, jsr107

Java 8 here. Is there any way with the [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) caching framework (or any other JSR-107 compatible framework for that matter) to be notified when a record is evicted out of the cache?

Maybe some kind of `EvictionEventListener` or something?

```
public class MyEvictionListener implements EvictionEventListener<String> {
    @Override
    public void onEvictionEvent(EvictionEvent eviction, String key) {
        // Now I have access to the String "key" that was evicted and
        // some information surrounding the eviction and I can do
        // whatever I want with this information....
    }
}
```

**Is there anything like this in Caffeine, Guava, Hazelcast, (basically "*JVM cache land*") etc.?**

Comment: `guava` has `LoadingCache` with a `removalListener` if you are interested

Comment: Not for JSR-107 implementation, but there exist an `EntryEvictedListener ` for `IMap` distributed map in Hazelcast. Please see here for details: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#listening-for-map-events

Comment: Caffeine supports both an asynchronous `RemovalListener` (Guava-style) and a synchronous `CacheWriter`. But JCache is pretty restrictive in what it offers and limits you to `CacheEntryListener`.

Comment: "Retagged" with java and caching, since a generic question and not specifically Java 8 related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eviction by time or by space ?

In JSR107 you must get an event for the former and must not for the latter.
See section 8.4 of the spec "8.4. Invocation of Listeners".

All JCache implementations must support eviction by time, and you would be aware of this via `javax.cache.event.CacheEntryExpiredListener<K, V>`. Expiry can be eager or lazy according to the implementation, items will not necessary disappear at the point at which their time limit occurs.

JCache allows for implementations to extend this with space based.

With Hazelcast you could do this

```
 <eviction size="50" max-size-policy="ENTRY_COUNT" eviction-policy="LRU"/>
```

to discard items from a cache according to a configurable space threshold. However, as this is implementation dependent, there's no JCache event for it.

JCache's *EXPIRED* event is produced by the system, cannot be directly triggered by the user. The *REMOVED* event is only for user initiated actions, such as `cache.remove(k)`. The other two kinds *CREATED* and *UPDATED* won't help here either.

Comment: I don't think `REMOVED` is actually so restrictive. The specification tends to refer to the JavaDoc rather than clarify intent. The JavaDoc is often unspecific or dictates implementation details. The TCK is fairly minimal, but even its tests are sometimes based on questionable assumptions. So whether `REMOVED` can include size evicted items seems to be an implementation choice.

Comment: That’s a good point. if you view whether space eviction produces an event is undefined  then you can’t rely on it — behaviour could vary between providers or if one provider changes their implementation from release to release. All told it seems JSR107 isn’t the solution to this need

Comment: Exactly. In Caffeine's provider, I decided to publish a removal event on size eviction. Doing otherwise seemed worse, in case the user needed to clean up resources. But I wouldn't want my application code to rely on undefined behavior. I think JCache is okay for framework integrations (e.g. Hibernate) where the touch points are simple, but otherwise using the native APIs probably better fits application needs that can be fairly diverse / complex / tricky.